# Rendering PDF from controller to view in Grails

Tags: pdf, grails, groovy

I am trying to pass a pdf document to my view from my controller,

i am using the render method that looks like :

```
        render (file: new File (result), fileName:"test.pdf", contentType:"application/pdf" )
```

where result is : "file:///D:/TempPartage/test.pdf"
The problem is that i got the current exception:

> Content type could not be determined for file: test.pdf. Stacktrace follows:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Content type could not be determined for file: test.pdf
>       at fr.mma.usage.EditionintercalaireController$$EQMXBXRn.copierPDF(EditionintercalaireController.groovy:154)
>       at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
>       at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
>       at fr.mma.use.logging.filter.HttpLoggingFilter.doFilter(HttpLoggingFilter.java:69)
>       at fr.mma.souse.authentication.AnnuaireCredentialCheckerFilter.doFilter(AnnuaireCredentialCheckerFilter.groovy:84)
>       at fr.mma.souse.security.mock.MockAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MockAuthenticationFilter.groovy:60)
>       at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
>       at fr.mma.use.navigation.NexturlValidationFilter.doFilter(NexturlValidationFilter.groovy:52)
>       at fr.mma.use.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.groovy:38)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What am i doing wrong?
Thx for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"file:///D:/TempPartage/test.pdf"` is looks like URL and not file path

two variants:

```
render (
    file: new URL(result).openStream(), //file could be stream
    fileName:"test.pdf", 
    contentType:"application/pdf" 
)
```

or

```
render (
    file: new File( new URL(result).toURI().getPath() ), 
    fileName:"test.pdf", 
    contentType:"application/pdf" 
)
```

Comment: Thx it works fine to render this file but now how got this error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response and sometimes if i double clic it doesn't appear